# filter incoming input value and show or hide divs in angular

Tags: angularjs, boonex-dolphin

I have a trivial problem out there. I need to make a filter search on the page with input . I'm using a boonex platform. I need to insert the input tag and it should hide or show the DIV blocks wich depends of value of input. this is the a code of my HTML page:

```
<ul id="navtabsidebar" class="nav nav-justified nav-tabs">
    <bx_repeat:tabs_name>
                <li  class="__status__">
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#__tab_name__"><i class="fa fa-__icon__"></i></a>
                </li>
    </bx_repeat:tabs_name>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" ng-app>
<input type="text" ng-model="filter">
<bx_repeat:tabs>
    <div id="__tab_name__" class="tab-pane __status__">
        <bx_repeat:users_list>
        <div class="memberUser">
            __user_avatar__
            __chat__
            </div>
        </bx_repeat:users_list>
    </div>
</bx_repeat:tabs>
    </div>
```

Does someone how any ideas? Thanks guys

Comment: Use ng-switch.. It may work.